# .env file variables are not visible in nest.js app with docker

Tags: docker, nestjs

I have nest.js application which is dockerised.Three images are created - for server, postgres db, and pgadmin4. All was working correctly. Then, I discovered that variables from .env file in root folder of the project are not read. Basically, whenever I invoke configService.get() method on ConfigService instance, I get undefined, through out entire project. I noticed it when I was setting jwt strategy authentication. Same with process.env.VARIABLE. Project is started with docker-compose up command. Code was taken from the project where server was not dockerised.

main.ts

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TransformInterceptor } from './transform.interceptor';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.enableCors();
  const configService = app.get(ConfigService);

  app.enableCors();
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());
  app.useGlobalInterceptors(new TransformInterceptor());

  const port = configService.get('PORT');
  const secret = configService.get('JWT_SECRET');

  // const port = process.env.PORT;
  // const secret = process.env.JWT_SECRET;

  console.log('port', port, 'secret', secret);

  await app.listen(port || 4250);
}
bootstrap();
```

app.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { UsersModule } from './users/users.module';
import { TaskModule } from './task/task.module';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
// import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config/dist';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
      envFilePath: `.env`,
    }),
    // TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
    //   type: 'postgres',
    //   host: 'db',
    //   port: 5432,
    //   username: 'postgres',
    //   password: 'postgres',
    //   database: 'postgres',
    //   autoLoadEntities: true,
    //   synchronize: true,
    // }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => {
        const isProduction = configService.get('STAGE') === 'prod';
        return {
          ssl: isProduction,
          extra: {
            ssl: isProduction ? { rejectUnauthorized: false } : null,
          },
          type: 'postgres',
          autoLoadEntities: true,
          synchronize: true,
          // host: configService.get('DB_HOST'),
          // port: configService.get('DB_PORT'),
          // username: configService.get('DB_USERNAME'),
          // password: configService.get('DB_PASSWORD'),
          // database: configService.get('DB_DATABASE'),
          host: 'db',
          port: 5432,
          username: 'postgres',
          password: 'postgres',
          database: 'postgres',
        };
      },
    }),
    UsersModule,
    TaskModule,
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:18-alpine AS base

WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./

## dev ##
FROM base AS dev
RUN npm i --frozen-lockfile
COPY . .
CMD ["npm", "run", "start:dev"]


## prod ##
FROM base AS prod
RUN npm ci --frozen-lockfile
COPY . .
RUN npm run build 
CMD ["npm", "run", "start:prod"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      target: dev
    ports:
      - 4250:4250
    volumes:
      - ./src:/app/src
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
  
  dbadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5050:80
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: admin@admin.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: pgadmin4
```

.env

```
JWT_SECRET=SUPERsecret123PAssWORd
PORT=4250

DB_HOST=db
DB_PORT=5432
DB_USERNAME=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=postgres
DB_DATABASE=postgres
```

What am I missing here? Should I avoid .env and instead define all variables in docker-compose.yml?

Comment: According to the given answer, this problem isn't reproducible and therefore not helpful.

Comment: I would still love to receive explanation on .env file naming so that similar problems could be avoided in future.

Comment: The problem is somewhere in your project in code or files you didn't provide in your question. I guess you have an ignore file that ignores `.env` files. But it's impossible to say, when you don't post that file. As I said, the problem in your question isn't reproducible with the information in your question. That makes your question useless for future users. You should try to create a [mcve] without React and post it here.

Answer (score 0):

All works now.
When .env file name is changed for .env.stage.dev or anything else, file is discoverable. Can't really tell why. Everything else was in order.

Also helped with debugging creating config.schema.ts with following content

```
import * as Joi from 'joi';

export const configSchemaValidation = Joi.object({
  // STAGE: Joi.string().required(),
  PORT: Joi.number().default(3000).required(),
  DB_HOST: Joi.string().required(),
  DB_PORT: Joi.number().default(5432).required(),
  DB_USERNAME: Joi.string().required(),
  DB_PASSWORD: Joi.string().required(),
  DB_DATABASE: Joi.string().required(),
});
```

and changing imports in app.module file

```
 ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
      envFilePath: [`.env.stage.dev`],
      validationSchema: configSchemaValidation,
    }),
```